# Assign a click listener to the info window, cannot navigate to the webpage Google Maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

The problem is that I cannot click on the URL "www.news.com" displayed on andoid map v2 inside custom infowindow of a marker. 
In xml layout file I have:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:background="#ADD8E6"
    android:text="www.google.gr"
    android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

In Java activity file I have:

```
 mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

            // Use default InfoWindow frame
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);

                TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
                tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
                TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
                tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

               // URL
               final TextView tvURL =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.web);
               tvURL.setText("www.news.com");
               Linkify.addLinks(tvURL, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
                // URL
```

The link is showing properly with blue color and underline, but I found the its just a dead link. Nothing is happening if we try to click it. What I have to do to make the link active?

New code inserted inside java file:

```
 mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);

            TextView tvTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            TextView tvSnippet = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

           // URL

                final TextView tvWeb =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.web);
                tvWeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.news.com"));
                        startActivity(viewIntent);
                    }
                });
```

XML used the same:

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/web"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:background="#ADD8E6"
    android:text="www.news.com"
    android:linksClickable="true"/>
```

Still problem exists..URL link is not active, I cannot open browser.

Now URL link is opening to mobile browser when I click on custom infowindow.

```
 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(39.686286, 19.838443)).title("Hi").snippet("Name, Surname, phone: 1093595, website: www.news.com").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon)));
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.news.com"));
            startActivity(viewIntent);


        }
    });
```

But I have around 300 markers and for each marker I wish to open a separate URL link. How can I implement this?

UPDATE CODE:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(36.84449, 22.99999)).title("KALOGRIA").snippet("Name: Messinia \nSurname: Stoupa \nphone: +99999999 \nwebsite: http://www.news.com/").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.location_icon)));


mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
    {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
    {
        //String webUrl = marker.getSnippet();
        String snippetStr = marker.getSnippet();
        String webUrl = snippetStr.substring(snippetStr.lastIndexOf("website:") + 1);
        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webUrl));
        startActivity(viewIntent);
    }
    });
```

Comment: Hack for forcing info window view liveness/interactivity: https://gist.github.com/corsair992/8313269

Answer (score 1):

Info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. So the view only response click as a whole view. For your case I suppose you have to use `GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener`, and then retrieve the web string to launch.

[**UPDATE1**]

Maybe you could try this way:

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
{

           @Override
           public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker thisMarker)
           {

                Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.news.com"));
                startActivity(viewIntent);                 

           }

});
```

[**UPDATE2**]

For the case you have several `Marker`s, and want to open different `Activity` when click each `Marker`, then one solution is to put `Activity` info to `Marker`'s `Snippet` as:

```
Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
 .position(...)
 .title(...)
 .snippet("http://www.news.com"); //put your activity info here
```

and then get it when click `Marker`:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker thisMarker)
{
         ... ...
     String snippetStr = thisMarker.getSnippet();
     String webUrl = snippetStr.substring(snippetStr.lastIndexOf("website:") + 1);
     Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(webUrl));
     startActivity(viewIntent);
}
```

Comment: @Thanos, how is going your issue?

Comment: I still have problem with link. It is not clickable. Please check my new code above and please help me to resolve this.

Comment: new code is under "New code inserted inside java file:" above

Comment: Just **UPDATE** answer, I am not sure this best solution, but could try it. Anyway this should launch your web.

Comment: Yes it is working fine. Thank you. Now I am trying to open different activity for each marker separate. Do you know how to do it? Or any examples I can see? Please the code above.

Comment: @Thanos, Ok I made one solution for your request, check my **UPDATE2**, hope you will accept it!

Comment: But inside snippet I have also other information (name, surname) I need to display except website : .snippet("Name, Surname, phone: 1093595, website: www.news.com")

Comment: `str = "Name, Surname, phone: 1093595, website: www.news.com"`, can you get `website` from `str`?

Comment: Is the webUrl getting from snippet only the URL string "www.nes.com"  and ignores all the other info like name, surname, phone?

Comment: from snippet you get whole string, then extract the `webUrl` that you need for launching activity. Hope this clear.

Comment: Thank you for you answers. I can launch URL for each marker  but having only the web activity inside snippet .snippet("http://www.news.com"); Do you have any example or site to see how to extract the whole string ""Name, Surname, phone: 1093595, http://website: www.news.com" from snippet and do a compare in order to extract the URL starting from "http" or "www" and launch it?

Comment: I just modified `onInfoWindowClick`, now it is a complete solution.

Comment: Unfortunately it crashes when click on the URL. check my "UPDATE CODE" above.

Comment: It is no reason crash, what's the `snippetStr` you got? and there is `website:` in it?

Comment: It finally worked. Basically the URL was captured with: String webUrl = snippetStr.substring(snippetStr.lastIndexOf("http:"); It is working fine! Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: @Thanos, happy finally help you solve the issue! Could you please upvote and accept my answer